# iphone: single sign on implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, single-sign-on

I have a situation where I have a couple of apps say App A, B, C and D

now A, B, C are part of the same package and if user jump among A, B, C the applications will not ask for username and password again (Single sign on for A, B, C)
 but it tries to access D the system will ask for credentials.

can you show me some way to attain this? Please enlighten me on this.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the keychain to share login information between A,B and C. Have a look at this http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html